Wordfence 502 Gateway Timeout on Login
I'm experiencing a 502 Gateway Timeout error during the login process of my WordPress site, specifically when Wordfence is enabled. The error log shows:
2024/07/24 11:32:51 [error] 1858364#1858364: *37144 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: xxx.xxx.x.xx, server: example.com, request: "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm- example.sock:", host: "example.com", referrer: "https://example.com/wp-login.php

The issue seems to occur only on the first login attempt after opening a new browser instance. Disabling Wordfence resolves the problem, which leads me to believe that the issue is related to Wordfence's settings.
Steps Taken:
Checked Wordfence logs and settings - When this scenario occurs the traffic logged as 200 response with logged in status. Usually it's logged as 302 response with redirection to home page instead 200 response in traffic which cause the timeout without re-direction.
Tried adjusting related configurations, including disabling the brute force module, but the issue persists.
Verified the issue disappears when Wordfence is disabled.
Thanks in advance for your help!
